# Google Maps on Checkout Magento

Tags: google-maps, magento, checkout

I want to add google map at one page checkout page in magento on shipping address form magento also capture latitude and longitude of customer

I am using magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px;width: 100%; margin: 0.6em;"></div>



 <!--Script Starts Here-->
<script>
     jQuery(function () {
    var lat = 44.88623409320778,
        lng = -87.86480712897173,
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

    //zoomControl: true,
    //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

    var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: true,
            panControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
            }
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

    var input = document.getElementById('billing:street2');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
        types: ["geocode"]
    });

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
        infowindow.close();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
        }

        moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
        jQuery('#billing\\:{{textbox name for latitude}}').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
        jQuery('#billing\\:{{textbox name for longitude}}').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#billing\\:company').val(event.latLng.lat());
        jQuery('#billing\\:fax').val(event.latLng.lng());
        infowindow.close();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            "latLng":event.latLng
        }, function (results, status) {
            console.log(results, status);
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                    placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                jQuery("#billing\\:street2").val(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
        });
    });

    function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
        marker.setIcon(image);
        marker.setPosition(latlng);
        infowindow.setContent(placeName);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can integrate [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to get the longitude and latitude of the customer.

> **Geocoding** is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.

Sample Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Sample Response:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>street_address</type>
  <formatted_address>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>1600</long_name>
   <short_name>1600</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</long_name>
   <short_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Mountain View</long_name>
   <short_name>Mountain View</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>San Jose</long_name>
   <short_name>San Jose</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Santa Clara</long_name>
   <short_name>Santa Clara</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>California</long_name>
   <short_name>CA</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse></address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>94043</long_name>
   <short_name>94043</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>37.4217550</lat>
    <lng>-122.0846330</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>37.4188514</lat>
     <lng>-122.0874526</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.4251466</lat>
     <lng>-122.0811574</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```